# TableStorage queryEntities sometimes returning 0 entries but no error

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

TableStorage & Nodejs

Using the function "queryEntities" sometimes result.entries.length is 0, even when I am pretty sure there are a lot of entries in the database. The "where" parameters are ok, but sometimes (maybe one every 100) it returns 0 entries. Not error returned. Just 0 entries.

And in my function that's causing troubles.

My theory is that the database sometimes is saturated because this function executes every 10 seconds and maybe sometimes before one finish another one starts and both operate over the same table, and instead of error it returns a length 0 , what is something awful.

There is any way to resolve this? Shouldn't it return error?

Comment: You could measure if your network has any package lost when doing the queries against the storage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior. In this particular scenario, please check for the presence of continuation tokens in the response. Presence of these tokens in the response indicate that there may be entities available matching the query and you should execute the same query again with the continuation token you received.

Please read this document for explanation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/query-timeout-and-pagination.

From this link:

> A query against the Table service may return a maximum of 1,000 items
>   at one time and may execute for a maximum of five seconds. If the
>   result set contains more than 1,000 items, if the query did not
>   complete within five seconds, or if the query crosses the partition
>   boundary, the response includes headers which provide the developer
>   with continuation tokens to use in order to resume the query at the
>   next item in the result set.

Comment: Thank you. The solution was the continuationToken when " the query did not complete within five seconds"